# Using intent anchor in Ionic app (Android) returns "Cannot display PDF file"

Tags: android, ionic-framework, square-connect

I am trying to integrate the Square Payment on my **Ionic 1** application using the Web API based on their docs [here](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/web-api-android/). They are using **intent anchor** to call the Square app and send appropriate payment details. But when I tried to implement, it gives me this error:

**Can't display PDF file** (*intent URL* cannot be opened)

Here's my code snippet:

```
var hrefString = 'intent://#Intent;';

var extrasObject = { /* extras */
    "action": "com.squareup.register.action.CHARGE",
    "package":"com.squareup",
    "S.browser_fallback_url":"<my-fallback-url>",
    "S.com.squareup.register.CLIENT_ID":"<my-client-id>",
    "S.com.squareup.register.WEB_CALLBACK_URI": "<registered-callback-uri>",
    "S.com.squareup.register.API_VERSION":"v1.3",
    "i.com.squareup.register.TOTAL_AMOUNT": 100,
    "S.com.squareup.register.CURRENCY_CODE":"USD",
    "S.com.squareup.register.TENDER_TYPES":"com.squareup.register.TENDER_CARD,com.squareup.register.TENDER_CARD_ON_FILE,com.squareup.register.TENDER_CASH,com.squareup.register.TENDER_OTHER"
};

// Generate intent anchor
for(var key in extrasObject) {
    hrefString += key + '=' + extrasObject[key] + ';';
}

// Convert string to URI
var intentURL = encodeURIComponent(hrefString + 'end');

window.open(intentURL, "_system", "location=no");
```

Prior to this implementation, I already install the **InAppBrowser** Cordova plugin [here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/).

Can someone help me on this one? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like an Ionic issue, maybe they restrict their url types?

Comment: Already thought about that and added solution to it. Still no luck.